# Import Angular JavaScript Modules into TypeScript

Tags: javascript, angularjs, typescript

I have bunch of Angular modules written in JavaScript and would like to import them into TypeScript. I tried using import and require, but it doesn't find my angular module since import checks for TypeScript Modules only.

```
import myModule= require('myModule');
```

Is there any other way to do this instead of converting my Js in TypeScript?

Comment: `var myModule= require('myModule');`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot use modules defined using `angular.module('my', [])` directly from TypeScript. Such notation is used just to register a module inside internal angularJS object. 
From good code prospective you have to redesign your angular modules to TypeScript/CommonJS/AMD modules and re-use them in your angular application.
But you can go another way:

1. create a hidden `div` element.
2. bootstrap an angular module you want to import on this div element. Here is  [link to angularJS documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.bootstrap) which may be helpful.
3. use next snippet to use service or whatewer else registered in your module: `angular.element(document.getElementById('myhiddendiv')).injector.invoke(function(YourService: any) { YouService.doDirtyJob(); })`.

But I would recommend to go with the first option.

Answer (score 1):

The import module looks for JS files too...

```
import $Module = require("myModule");
```

This should work fine! In TypeScript you call the module with '$' and use it like:

```
$Module.createdWhateverFunctionYouMade(parameters);
```

In this case 'myModule' is the Javascript file.